# Electron apps show notify-osd notifications incorrectly

Tags: 16.04, notification, notify-osd, electron

I use [Nylas N1 email client](https://github.com/nylas/N1/) which is built using [Electron](https://github.com/electron/electron).

It used to present me with notify-osd notifications on Ubuntu 15.10.

However, since the upgrade notifications look as follows:

[image]

Comment: same for me with slack notifications

Comment: It's an Electron issue that is discussed in [Linux Notifications Not Showing Properly](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/465#issuecomment-214392962).

Comment: Thanks @JorgeCastro! This question is older than the other. Thus, isn't the other question a duplicate of this one?

Comment: I happened to run into that one first, either way works, maybe perhaps even a question merge. Having them linked to each other right off the bat is a good start though.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Run this command

`sudo touch /usr/lib/libunity-electron_notification_fix`

then reboot ubunutu

[Source](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/465#issuecomment-206582829)

Comment: What will this file do? Will it make Electron notifications use `notify-osd` again or suppress them completely?

Comment: It actually brings back the `notify-osd` notifications. Great!